# How to get next child of root as the parent via stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `Label` (IdLabel int, IdParentLabel int , Name varchar(30))

```
Insert Into Label Values (1, null, 'root')
Insert Into Label Values (2, 1, 'child1')
Insert Into Label Values (3, 1, 'child2')
Insert Into Label Values (4, 1, 'child3')
Insert Into Label Values (5, 2, 'grandchild1')
Insert Into Label Values (6, 3, 'grandchild2') 
Insert Into Label Values (7, 4, 'grandchild3') 
Insert Into Label Values (8, 5, 'grandgrandchild1') 
Insert Into Label Values (9, 5, 'grandgrandchild2')
```

I want to write a stored procedure which will take `@IdLabel` as input parameter and will return the top most parent's `IdLabel` (definition of top most parent: the next child of root among the branches, so root will never be considered as top parent), but it is always returning the root as the parent.

Sample:

- `Exec StoredProcedure 8` will return 2 as it is the next child
- `Exec StoredProcedure 9` also returns 2
- `Exec StoredProcedure 6` will return 3

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckParent
    @IdLabel int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TopParent int
    
    SELECT @TopParent = IdParentLabel
    FROM Label
    WHERE IdLabel = @IdLabel
    
    WHILE @TopParent IS NOT NULL AND @TopParent <> 1
    BEGIN
        SET @IdLabel = @TopParent
        
        SELECT @TopParent = IdParentLabel
        FROM Label
        WHERE IdLabel = @IdLabel
    END
    
    IF @TopParent IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TopParent = IdLabel
        FROM Label
        WHERE IdParentLabel IS NULL AND IdLabel <> 1
        ORDER BY IdLabel
        OFFSET 0 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    END
    
    SELECT @TopParent AS TopParent
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a looping architecture, you can use the built-in recursive nature of CTEs for this type of task, for example

```
declare @IdLabel int = 9;

with p as (
    select IdLabel, IdParentLabel
    from label
    where idLabel = @IdLabel
    union all
    select l.IdLabel, l.IdParentLabel
    from Label l
    join p on l.IdLabel = p.IdParentLabel
    where l.idParentLabel is not null
)
select top(1) idLabel
from p
order by IdParentLabel;
```

Comment: You can't rely on the ordering of the IDs. Instead remove `where l.idParentLabel is not null`, and on the outside do `where idParentLabel is null` instead of the `order by`